# Load dump audible issue and large output ripple issue

Tags: circuit-protection, over-voltage-protection

We have a load dump circuit in one of the boards and which is designed using MAX16129UAAGA IC. The under-voltage and over-voltage range of this IC is 3 V and 31.5 V respectively. Currently, we are facing the below issues.

1. **Audible issue**: When the input voltage reaches above the overvoltage, we observed some audible noise from the board. Since the gate voltage is continuously switching with the frequency of 2.24 kHz (audible frequency), this may be the reason for that.
2. **Large ripple at the output (VCC_LD)**: With the same above scenario, also found a very large output ripple which may damage the downstream devices.
   [image]
   [image]
   Could you please suggest what could be the reason for this and how to overcome this issue?

Comment: As I understand, this is the intended behaviour of the MAX16129, description is on page 8 in the datasheet, section "Overvoltage Limiter (MAX16129)"

Comment: @jens Yes, but how do we reduce the large voltage variation (ripple) in the VCC_LD? what could be done? please suggest. Currently, we have done some experiments by adding the Bulk cap at VCC_LD and measured the voltage again, and found some reduction in Ripple from 6V to 2.4V. Still, this 2.4V ripple is not good for design. So please suggest how we can reduce further.

Comment: In your schematic C36, C37 and C48 are marked DNP. You need a large capacitor at VCC_LD to hold the voltage while the protection chip disconnects the input. However, a big capacitor introduces high inrush currents, that may also be critical. What is the typical load current here?

Comment: @jens Typical load current is 300mA

Comment: @Jens MAX16129, this chip will not disconnect the load during the over-voltage, instead of that it will regulate the output in the linear mode so the bulk cap will not introduce the inrush current.

Comment: As you see, there is no linear regulation, just a hysteretic on/off regulation. To reduce the ripple, you can add an R/C damping element between VCC_LD and GND. Try 100 µF and 2.2 ohm in series.

Answer (score 1):

My cursory reading of the datasheet,
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX16128-MAX16129.pdf 
suggests this is not a part I would design in:

- The block diagram provides essentially no functional or behavioral information
- Gate drive current is poorly specified (minimums only)
- OV operation is described as a "switched linear" mode, with undefined peak current, pulse duration and so on
- No discussion of SOA and selection of MOSFETs or heatsinking is provided (likely in part due to the ambiguity of the previous point)
- Operation is apparently unlimited, i.e. pulsing continues as long as the overvoltage condition is maintained; no device temperature sensing is performed
- A zener is apparently required to limit V<sub>GS</sub> but why is not explained; data seems to suggest the bootstrap can supply about 9V and that's it

That said, there are some advantages to such a mechanism:

- It can in principle be cheaper; at a couple dollars each, this part isn't especially cheap, but it is much cheaper than a more fully developed part like LT4363 (~$10)
- No current sense resistor is required
- Pulsed operation can potentially extend the SOA of MOSFETs subject to 2nd breakdown, broadening the set of applicable devices
- Operation could be thermally limited; though there is no mechanism for this chip to thermally link with, or otherwise monitor, the pass device, so that's a very limited possibility here

Other downsides include the point you raise (output ripple), but I would not be particularly concerned about this as ripple voltage plus transients in a normally operating automotive or industrial environment can easily do the same, and if the load cannot tolerate those, you have bigger problems whether or not the protective device creates ripple of its own.  Also note that this device only emits such pulses during overvoltage (fault) operation, which is hopefully momentary (i.e., load dump pulse).  The most likely victim of such ripple is electrolytic capacitors at the load input, dissipating the AC as heat; a short burst of ripple will not appreciably heat them up.